# angular material 2 custom theme button contrast

Tags: angular, angular-material2

i just started using angular and angular material theming, created new theme with custom palettes.

to generate custom palette i used this tool http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5

it works great https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-theme-button-contrast?file=styles.scss but only problem is how i can have button text color white over green background ? i tried different numbers but nothing worked

```
$my-primary: mat-palette($mat-my-green, 500, 50, 50);
$my-accent: mat-palette($mat-my-black, 500, 900, 400);
```

using

```
.mat-raised-button{
    line-height: 29px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    &.mat-primary{
      color: mat-contrast($mat-keldano-green,900); // get the contrast color
    }}
```

this works but i don't think this is good solution 
another problem is stepper component step numbers also have contrast issue
[image]

Comment: worked for me excellent !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button uses `500` as the background color - at least in your setup. In your config, you state that contrast color to `500` is `#000000`. Set it to `#ffffff` and you're good to go.

The `contrast` property tells Material what color to choose over the color background. So the line `100: #000000` means "*when the background is `100`, use `#000000` as the text color*". This ensures text readability.

Material uses 3 color shades for their elements. These colors are selected by calling `mat-palette`.

```
$my-primary: mat-palette($mat-my-green, 500, 50, 50);
```

That call tells Material to use `500` as the "main" shade, `50` as the darker and `50` as the lighter. Therefore the button has `500` color and then the contrast color get's selected for the text.

To make the text over 500 white:

```
contrast: (50 : #000000,
100 : #000000,
200 : #000000,
300 : #000000,
400 : #000000,
500 : #ffffff,
600 : #ffffff,
700 : #ffffff,
800 : #ffffff,
900 : #ffffff,
A100 : #000000,
A200 : #000000,
A400 : #000000,
A700 : #000000,
));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-theme-button-contrast-8ma1fp?file=styles.scss

[image: white on green]

Comment: Thanks it works!! can you please explain how it works ? can't i use other numbers having white color like 600, 700 under contrast ?

Comment: @Yasir I have expanded my answer to try to explain a bit more. It would make me happy if you accept the answer. Good luck coding.

Comment: hi @kvetis, I see you are pretty much into angular material themes. can you please have a look here and help me? I've read closely your answer but didn't work for me. I feel like it's a small adjustment and I'll be good, but nothing until now. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77066285/angular-material-16-theme-constrast