# Angular Material 16 Theme constrast

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes, angular16, angular-material-theming

I've migrated my project from Angular 14 to angular 16, following the migration guide. Everything is fine, except the material theme. Everything seems to be loaded correctly, but the contrast colors are not being applied correctly.

For example, before migration, color 800: #ff8700 has his contrast as white, working great. Now, the same pallet (same 800: #ff8700 with contrast white), but it is rendered with a contrast color black. There's the images:

Before migration:
[image]

After migration:
[image]

My pallet is the following:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$my-palette: (
  50: #fff7e0,
  100: #ffeab1,
  200: #ffdc7e,
  300: #ffd04a,
  400: #ffc41f,
  500: #ffba00,
  600: #ffac00,
  700: #ff9900,
  800: #ff8700,
  900: #ee6001,
  contrast: (
    50: mat.get-color-from-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, '50-contrast'),
    100: mat.get-color-from-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, '100-contrast'),
    200: mat.get-color-from-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, '200-contrast'),
    300: mat.get-color-from-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, '300-contrast'),
    400: mat.get-color-from-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, '400-contrast'),
    500: #ffffff,
    600: #ffffff,
    700: #ffffff,
    800: #ffffff,
    900: #ffffff
  )
);


$my-primary: mat.define-palette($my-palette, 800, 500, 800, 800);
$my-accent:  mat.define-palette($my-palette, 800, 500, 800, 800);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: $my-accent
  ),
  density: 0
));
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
```

I've tried many variation, checked github issue [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27758) but can't seems to find a way to make my contrast being applied correctly. Seems that angular decides to apply black instead of my defined color.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening on legacy material components. If yes you can add the following lines in your code after "@include mat .core();"

```
@include mat.legacy-core();
@include mat.all-legacy-component-typographies();
```

Also, add `@include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($your-custom-palette);` for legacy component themes

Comment: what do you mean for legacy material components? Are buttons legacy components?! And what is $olp-client-theme?

Comment: changed that name for better clarity, it is the color palette you are using, i.e. $indigo-palette.
Now coming to main question, Legacy components, so from angular material 15, It has migrated to MDC-based angular material components and all components that were used in your project may have been converted to legacy components. To verify you can check import statements in you application components

Comment: yea, they were all converted to legacy, but I converted them to "normal" components. So all my components are not legacy, and btw, the `@include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($my-palette);` didn't work. This is so frustrating, I have everything ready to deploy, but this silly issue it taking so much from me, I'm not sure what to do anymore. It crossed my mind to change the pallete itself, but I mean, it should be required to change the colors of your app because of some framework change...

Comment: New components have some design and api changes which you might need to verify according to the new mdc specifications. That might be the reason your component look slightly different. Fot eg in mat dialogs the  padding for dialog has been changed and similarly there are many small changes across different components

Comment: Additionally if you were overriding some css classes for mat components they might need to been changed as well as these new component have different classes containing -mdc- in class names